# Fragment with actionbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

When I add a fragment to my xml file, it shows all the content but not the fragment's action bar. How can I change the default behaviour to show the actionbar too?

Comment: a fragment does not contain an actionbar an activity does

Comment: What you want is probably a `FragmentActivity`.

Answer (score 2):

From the Fragment, in your onCreate() method, you can try calling

```
getActivity().getActionBar().show();
```

you can set the title by using

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("title");
```

Comment: You could also use the support libs. So it would be getSupportActionBar()